# Analytical solution for pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

If I have this pde with boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$

$ u_{xx}+ u = 1 $

How would I solve this analytically? I have forgotten how to do this, can anyone show me? Thank you

Comment: This is not a PDE

Comment: @italy : a PDE involves a function of not only one variable, but several variables. In your question one variable is $x$. What is the other variable ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the complementary solution $u_C$, substitute $u(x)=\exp(\lambda x)$. For the particular solution $u_P(x)$, substitute $u(x)=a$. The general solution will be $u(x)=u_P(x)+u_C(x)$. It will have $2$ constants, which you can determine from the boundary conditions: It will give you a system of linear equations for them.